How to access the Results text that are generated in copilot post starting the search of a text? I am unable to locate its exact Xpath
I am trying to extract the results after commencing the web search for a keyword in copilot. I am able to locate the search bar, but I am unable to locate the search results on the website. I am extracting it to paste it into an Excel sheet. I am using Selenium, OpenPyxl, Pandas and Chrome WebDriver.
Community.... Please share your insights.
I have tried the below code, but it ain't helping:
#Function to retrieve the result text with retries
def get_result_text(driver, company_name, retries=3, wait_time=30):
    for attempt in range(retries):

        try:
            #Wait for the result container to load
            result_host = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cib-chat-main"))
            ).shadow_root
            print(f"Shadow result host found for {company_name}")

            shadow_root_result1 = get_shadow_root(driver, result_host)
            result_turn_host = shadow_root_result1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cib-chat-turn")
            shadow_root_result2 = get_shadow_root(driver, result_turn_host)
            message_group_host = shadow_root_result2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cib-message-group")
            shadow_root_result3 = get_shadow_root(driver, message_group_host)
            message_host = shadow_root_result3.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cib-message")
            shadow_root_result4 = get_shadow_root(driver, message_host)
            shared_host = shadow_root_result4.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cib-shared")
            shadow_root_result5 = get_shadow_root(driver, shared_host)
            result_text_element = shadow_root_result5.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div")
            print(f"Result text located for {company_name}")

            # Extract the text content from the results
            return result_text_element.text


Getting an error message of below:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63878/devtools/browser/2764cdc1-f139-425f-9774-b7ed1788f4bf
Columns in the DataFrame: Index(['Company'], dtype='object')
Shadow root 1 found for Plastic Omnium
Shadow roots 2 and 3 found for Plastic Omnium
Search initiated for Plastic Omnium
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Timeout error processing Plastic Omnium, attempt 1 of 3
Timeout error processing Plastic Omnium, attempt 2 of 3
Timeout error processing Plastic Omnium, attempt 3 of 3
Timeout error processing Plastic Omnium: Message: 
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF766E8EEA2+31554]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766E07ED9]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766CC872A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D18434]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D1853C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D5F6A7]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D3D06F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D5C977]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D3CDD3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D0A33B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766D0AED1]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF767198B1D+3217341]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7671E5AE3+3532675]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7671DB0E0+3489152]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF766F3E776+750614]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766E1375F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766E0EB14]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766E0ECA2]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF766DFE16F]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF8940E7344+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF89595CC91+33]


What is the error message? If you do not share it, we can only guess.

thanks for the question, i just re-edited my question. Hoping for assistance.

At first glance, I can not see how this stacktrace related to shared code. I suppose the get_shadow_root function could not found the "Plastic Omnium" thing. Note that I am little confused about the TensorFlow Lite statement in the stacktrace.

Herein, get_shadow_root is used becasue copilot has kept shadow roots, so that it will become difficult to trace the result elements
and Plastic Omnium is a company name, It is just used for reference to search.
Tensorflow lite is being used because i am triggering python to start webdriver to process my search
